# FOSElasticaBundle configuration with Symfony 5 and AWS Elasticsearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, symfony, elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch, foselasticabundle

I am trying to connect to an AWS Elasticsearch domain using FOSElasticaBundle (version v6.0.0-beta4). According to the documentation, this bundle uses ruflin/Elastica bundle. After researching the documentation and the related questions here, I could find some examples and configuration that I implemented, however, I am getting an error related to the elastica configuration. My config:

```
//config/packages/fos_elastica.yaml

fos_elastica:
    clients:
        default:
            url: 'aws-elasticsearch-domain-url'
            aws_access_key_id: 'access-key'
            aws_secret_access_key: 'secret-key'
            aws_region: "aws-region"
            transport: "AwsAuthV4"
    indexes:
        (indexes configuration...)
```

When populating the indexes, I am getting this error related to the AwsAuthV4 transport parameter:

```
In AwsAuthV4.php line 43:
                                                                         
  Attempted to load class "SignatureV4" from namespace "Aws\Signature".  
  Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?
```

I am unsure whether this is not supported, not properly configured, or something else.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that when you are using `FOSElasticaBundle` you have installed also package called `aws/aws-sdk-php`. This package will guarantee that calss `Aws\Signature\SignatureV4` will be loaded aswell.

In case you have still this problem remember to do `composer dump-autoload` in the console.

Comment: is existing elastica bundle works for AWS opensearch?